# Can somebody explain this behavior in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I have an image that I'm rotating and moving 
[image: Original position]

And when the rotation angle is negative the image moves as expected.
[image: Negative angle]

But when the angle is positive it moves it's origing point to the left
[image: Positive angle]

Can anybody explain this behavior, and how to solve it?

Here is the code

```
import pygame, sys
import math

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 400))
wrench = pygame.image.load('prueba.bmp')
white = (255,255,255)


ox = 20
oy = 32
running = True
posX = 100 - ox
posY = 100 - oy


pygame.init()
while running:
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running=0
        screen.blit(wrench, (posX, posY))
    if(pygame.time.get_ticks() <= 20000):
        screen.fill(white)
        t = pygame.time.get_ticks() / 1000
        ang = math.degrees(math.pi / 2 * math.cos(math.pi * t))
        #ang = math.pi / 2 * math.cos(math.pi * t)
        print(ang)
        posX = 100 + (50 * math.cos(math.pi * t)) - ox 
        posY = 100 + (20 * math.sin(math.pi * t)) - oy
        rotated_wrench = pygame.transform.rotate(wrench, ang)
        screen.blit(rotated_wrench, (posX, posY))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior? Should it move like a real wrench?

Comment: No, what I dont understand is why its origin point moves so much when the angle is positive

Comment: And what behavior do you expect?

Comment: If you want to rotate around an anchor point other than the center, I can show you an example.

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue?

Comment: Just in case you (or somebody else) want to rotate something around an arbitrary point, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49413006/6220679).

Answer (score 1):

This line is setting the X coordinate of the bliting:

```
posX = 100 + (50 * math.cos(math.pi * t)) - ox
```

The cosine is positive from 0 to 90 degrees and 270 to 0, which is the right side of a circle; and negative otherwise.

This is making the value to oscillate between `100 + 50 - ox` and `100 - 50 - ox`

If you want to keep the horizontal position to not oscillate in both directions, you should use the absolute value:

```
posX = 100 + (50 * math.fabs(math.cos(math.pi * t))) - ox
```